# Find equation of plane of the given question

Tags: vectors, analytic-geometry

Find equation of plane through $P(-2,1,7)$ that is perpendicular to the plane $4x-2y+2z=-1$ and $3x+3y-6z=5$

Comment: $(4,-2,2)$ is perpendicular to the first plane, and $(3,3,-6)$ to the second. Then their [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) $(4,-2,2)\times(3,3,-6)=(6,30,18)$ is perpendicular to both. The plane you are looking for should be of the form $6x+30y+18z=d$. Imposing that $P$ satisfies that equation, gives the value of $d=144$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$N_1= \langle4,-2,2\rangle$ and $N_2= \langle3,3,-6\rangle$ are normal vectors to the given planes.

The common perpendicular $N=N_1\times N_2$ is the normal vector to the new plane.

$N= \langle6,30,18\rangle$, thus the equation of the desired plane is $$6x+30y+18Z=d$$

Where $d=144$ is found  from the given point.

Thus we have $$ 6x +30y+18Z=144$$ which simplifies to $$ x +5y+3Z=48$$

Comment: @shasha Thank you for your attention.

Comment: You don't even have to solve for $d$, as the vector equation of the plane is $$6x+30y+18z=6(-2)+30(1)+18(7)$$ if the plane passes through $P(-2,1,7)$.

Comment: @Bernard That is what I had in mind when I said solve for d.

Comment: I guess so, nut I thought usrful to insist, as too many students tend so solve through linear systems instead of exploiting what they know.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

The normal vector of your new plane, must be perpendicular to both of the normal vectors of the previous two planes.

Comment: How to find the normal Vector?

Comment: Do you know how to find the equation for a plane passing through 3 points?

Comment: @shasha If the equation of the plane is $ax+by+cz=d$, then $(a,b,c)$ is perpendicular to the plane. This is because $ax+by+cz=0$ is a translation of the plane and can be re-written as $(a,b,c)\cdot(x,y,z)=0$, which is saying that the dot product of $(a,b,c)$ and the points of the plane $(x,y,z)$ is zero, i.e. are perpendicular.

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout yes I know and for this question ,there’s only 1 point given  which is p(-2,1,7)